# Having some issues with CKeditor when i move from localhost to hosted

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Having some issues with CKeditor when i move from localhost to hosted.

Works fine locally, as soon as I move it to the server I am getting these issues in console and the editor doesnt appear. It also breaks the JS.

> ckeditor.js:258 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of
>   undefined at Object.d (ckeditor.js:258) at e (ckeditor.js:259) at
>   Array.y (ckeditor.js:259) at v (ckeditor.js:259) at ckeditor.js:260

Comment: could you prepare some live example or describe more details

Answer (score 0):

There might possibility that ckEditor tried to load lang js

Try to include this : -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/ckeditor/lang/en.js"></script>
```

And also set configuration language

```
config.language = 'en';
```

Comment: i have included this but still editor doesn't appear

Comment: this is my index.php code <script type="text/javascript" src ="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/ckeditor/lang/en.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor" id ="editor"></textarea>

Comment: assets/ckeditor/lang have you check the file is available at path?

Answer (score 0):

See the workarounds in [this github issue](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor/issues/44). They suggest:

- setting a constant in your code to tell CKEditor what its base path is (see also [this part of the CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basepath))
- loading CKEditor from a CDN instead of locally

Comment: in case of cdn it is working fine but the problem is how to upload image with cdn

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

You are getting the error from only including the `ckeditor4.js` file on server, with this error becoming raised when CKE attempts to load other features such as plugins and languages but cannot find these files in the basepath folder. You can confirm this from the network tab in browser devtools, as CKE attempts to load features, then cannot find them.

#### Option 1: Link to a CDN Bundle

CKE offers 3 primary bundles (basic, standard, full) which offer a choice between features and page load. [More info here.](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/)

#### Option 2: Include Necessary Files

Make the extra files available on your server.
Here's a gulp task which bundles everything from the ckeditor node module folder (excluding the sample).

```
gulp.task("copy-ckeditor", function () {
    // Check and copy languages in config.ckEditorLanguages
    var isIncluded = function(path) {
        var found = false,
            lang = path.split('lang')[1];

        if (lang) {
            for (var i in config.ckEditorLanguages) {
                if (lang.indexOf(config.ckEditorLanguages[i]) != -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    },
    copyFile = function(stream) {
        stream.pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildPath.js + "lib/ckeditor"));
    };

    return gulp.src([
            "node_modules/ckeditor/**/*.*",
            "!node_modules/ckeditor/samples",
            "!node_modules/ckeditor/samples/**/*"
        ])
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
            if (file.path.indexOf("lang") != -1) {
                if (isIncluded(file.path)) {
                    copyFile(stream);
                }
            } else {
                copyFile(stream);
            }
            return stream;
        }));
});
```

#### Option 3: Build and Host Your Own Custom Bundle

If you want to use a single file load, you can use the [CKE4 Builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) allowing you to customise built-in plugins.

Comment: in case of cdn it is working fine but the problem is how to upload image with cdn

Comment: you'll need your own CDN / hosting / service for that.

Comment: should i talk to hosting provider for cdn/hosting/service

Comment: Depends on your needs. You could probably get away with using Firebase or Azure, or similar cloud service. Depending on usage, it can be "free". Some aspects include whether the content is sensitive or not. AWS is one of the best commercial options.

Comment: i have tried with easy image but i don't know how to integrate can you please help me to do integration

Comment: This comment thread is off topic. I suggest asking a new question based on integration & configuration for image upload hosting.

Comment: actually i have reached my questions limit.that's why i'm asking here